# How can I keep an inline SVG from displaying at an arbitrary height without giving it (or its parent) an explicit height?

Tags: css, svg

Below is a simplified layout that uses Bootstrap 3. The middle column in the row contains an inline SVG which provides a transition of sorts from the blue box to the green box.

Why do I want to do this? Styling SVG with browser CSS is cool! Moreover, doing so means I don't have to generate a bunch of PNGs for every possible row height and color combination to which I might apply this design element.

While I could use JS to dynamically set the height of the col-* divs based on the tallest non-SVG-containing one, it seems there should be a way to do this with CSS.

Note that I've tried setting `display: flex` for the `.row` element (it's
commented out in the style sheet). While it does ensure that the columns have equal heights, it has the effect of growing the content divs rather than shrinking the style one.

This [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EDn1simMbpSjUTtSS0a3?p=preview) is included in case you, like me, find it a little easier to work with than a StackOverflow snippet.

```css
html, body.stackoverflow-snippet {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  /*
   * Ultimately I would use the following rule to ensure the columns are equal
   * height, since their content is dynamic, but the problem is less obvious
   * when this rule is in effect.
   */
  /* display: flex; */
}

.row.desired-result div {
  /*
   * To see the desired effect, set the height to any known value. In my case, I
   * can't set the height of the divs explicitly the because user-generated
   * content populates these divs and may change their height.
   */
  height: 35px;
}

.row .rounded {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
}

svg circle {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body class="stackoverflow-snippet">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- first row: desired result -->
    <div class="row desired-result">
      <div class="blue col-xs-6">Desired result</div>
      <div class="green rounded col-xs-1">
        <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="inline-svg inlined-svg" viewBox="90 20 10 60" role="img">
          <circle r="50" cy="50" cx="50"></circle>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="green col-xs-5">(explicit height)</div>
    </div>
    <!-- second row: just a visual break to separate the rows of interest -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <!-- third row: natural height -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="blue col-xs-6">Ack!</div>
      <div class="green rounded col-xs-1">
        <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="inline-svg inlined-svg" viewBox="90 20 10 60" role="img">
          <circle r="50" cy="50" cx="50"></circle>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="green col-xs-5">(natural height)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the SVG `position: absolute`. Then the "100%" height will be measured against its parent container.  As long as you also remember to set the parent cell to `position: relative`, to make it into a suitable containing block.

```
.svg-container {
  position: relative;
}

.inline-svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

We also add a non-breaking space to the SVG cell to stop it collapsing to zero height when you make the SVG absolute.

```
.svg-container::before {
  content: '\a0'
}
```

The result:

```css
html, body.stackoverflow-snippet {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  /*
   * Ultimately I would use the following rule to ensure the columns are equal
   * height, since their content is dynamic, but the problem is less obvious
   * when this rule is in effect.
   */
  /* display: flex; */
}

.row.desired-result div {
  /*
   * To see the desired effect, set the height to any known value. In my case, I
   * can't set the height of the divs explicitly the because user-generated
   * content populates these divs and may change their height.
   */
  height: 35px;
}

.row .rounded {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
}

svg circle {
  fill: blue;
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
}

.svg-container::before {
  content: '\a0'
}

.inline-svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body class="stackoverflow-snippet">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- first row: desired result -->
    <div class="row desired-result">
      <div class="blue col-xs-6">Desired result</div>
      <div class="green rounded col-xs-1">
        <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="inline-svg inlined-svg" viewBox="90 20 10 60" role="img">
          <circle r="50" cy="50" cx="50"></circle>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="green col-xs-5">(explicit height)</div>
    </div>
    <!-- second row: just a visual break to separate the rows of interest -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <!-- third row: natural height -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="blue col-xs-6">Ack!</div>
      <div class="green rounded col-xs-1 svg-container">
        <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="inline-svg inlined-svg" viewBox="90 20 10 60" role="img">
          <circle r="50" cy="50" cx="50"></circle>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="green col-xs-5 svg-container">
        (natural height)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks, Paul. One question and one note -- the question: any idea how the browser decides to render the SVG 314.91 pixels high? It seems totally arbitrary to me. The note: the pseudo-class on the SVG container is unnecessary if the `display: flex` rule is uncommented for `.row`.

Comment: The height of the SVG is due to a combination of the `viewBox` aspect ratio (width to height ratio => 10 : 60) and the width of the column (from class `col-xs-1`).  So if the column is 100px width, the height of the SVG will be 600px  
 The actual height will depend on the width of the browser window because the `col-xs-1` width is a percentage.